# Parsing double to String is not accepted in function

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to convert a double variable to string to upload it as part of a http post request to the server:

```
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "fecha_inicio": _fechaInicioBBDD,
      "fecha_fin": _fechaFinalBBDD,
      "latitud": _controllerLatitud.text,
      "longitud": _controllerLongitud.text,
      "calle": _controllerDireccion.text,
      "descripcion": _controllerDescripcion.text,
      "tipo_aviso": tipoAviso,
      "activar_x_antes": double.parse(_horas.toString())

    });
```

The parameter  `"activar_x_antes": double.parse(_horas.toString())` is throwing an exception when executing the app:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

The value for `_horas = 4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "fecha_inicio": _fechaInicioBBDD,
      "fecha_fin": _fechaFinalBBDD,
      "latitud": _controllerLatitud.text,
      "longitud": _controllerLongitud.text,
      "calle": _controllerDireccion.text,
      "descripcion": _controllerDescripcion.text,
      "tipo_aviso": tipoAviso,
      "activar_x_antes": _horas.toString()

    });
```

`_horas.toString()`

Answer (score 4):

When you are doing:

```
double.parse(_horas.toString())
```

this is converting `_horas` to a `String` and then *again* to a `double`.
Instead, only call `toString()`:

```
"activar_x_antes": _horas.toString()
```

Comment: Just an important note: if you need to reduce the size of the output, you should use ```.toStringAsFixed(int fractionDigits)``` or ```toStringAsExponential([int? fractionDigits])```  like described in the docs here https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/double-class.html#instance-methods

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a closer look at why this is happening.

You have value `_horas = 4.0`;  which is a `double`, you are trying to convert it to `String` to send it to the server. However, you are using `double. parse`.

Let's look at the [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html) doc. it says "Parse source as a double literal and return its value." in fact, you are parsing a number *String* back to `double` again!

What you can do is either

```
"activar_x_antes": _horas.toString()
```

or

```
"activar_x_antes": '$_horas'
```

I hope the explanation helps.

Comment: How is this any different to any of the answers provided below?

Comment: haha, I was type didn't notice three are other answers, that happens! sorry.

Comment: ha, np. You did still provide an alternative of using string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`http.post`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html) states:

> `body` sets the body of the request. It can be a `String`, a `List<int>` or a `Map<String, String>`.

Since you are passing a `Map`, all keys and values in your `Map` are required to be `String`s.  You should not be converting a `String` to a `double` as one of the `Map` values.